# Android Programming: Alphabetically Order ListView

Tags: android, listview, sql-order-by, alphabetical

As the title says, how can I do this?
I've looked but can't find the answer.
It's really annoying me now.
This is for my file browser, I've tried using Collections.sort() on the array that gets added to the ListView but that didn't do anything!

Help :'( :'( :'(

Comment: I assume when you say you ran Collections.sort() on an array you mean an ArrayList.  What does the ArrayList contain, is it an ArrayList of Strings for example?  Show the code where you were using Collections.sort() so we can see what you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this existing question: [Sorting Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635708/sorting-android-listview)